# using if and evaluate in excel vba to convert during runtime cell data into text

Tags: excel, vba

Using IF and EVALUATE in excel vba how to convert during runtime cell data of a column into text to filter data based on user's input?
I have posted similar query  [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/751365-autofilter-problem-wildcard-filtering-numbers-space-without-space.html)

Here is the posted issue:

The AutoFilter given below filters records with PinCodes "600 083" if varPin = "083".
But this AutoFilter does not filter records with PinCodes "600083" if varPin = "083".
Code:

```
Dim varPin As String
Dim PinWithWildCard As String
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("D1:Q100") 'D has Names. Q has Email IDs.
varPin = "083"
PinWithWildCard = "*" & varPin & "*"
      rng.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=PinWithWildCard  'field number is from the one set in rng and has PinCodes
```

I checked the format of the cells having these PinCodes and they are set in GENERAL and are aligned in Left as Charaters.
I also tried PinWithWildCard = "=*" & varPin & "*" but it does not work.
Kindly suggest as to how to make this filter numbers set as general with space and without space. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you're working with not so large data set, you can try this:

```
Sub Sample()

Dim myfilter() As String, varpin As String, PinWithWildCard as String
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range


Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("$D$1:$Q$100")
ReDim myfilter(0 To 0)
varpin = "083"
PinWithWildCard = "*" & varpin & "*"

ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Value Like PinWithWildCard Then
        myfilter(UBound(myfilter)) = cel.Value
        ReDim Preserve myfilter(0 To UBound(myfilter) + 1)
    End If
Next cel

rng.AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:=myfilter, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Above filters all values with `O83` in it.
Hope this works for you. :)